# Chartjs-plugin-zoom drag option doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, real-time, chartjs-plugin-zoom

Using Chart.js with chartjs-plugin-zoom and chartjs-plugin-streaming the drag option shows the selected area but doesn't resize.
The wanted effect is to select a specific area and view only the selection, with x and y axes resizing accordingly.

This is the code:

```js
const options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction:{
        intersect: false 
    },
    plugins: {
        zoom: {
            pan: {
                enabled: true,
                mode: 'xy',
                modifierKey: 'ctrl'
            },
            zoom: {
                mode: 'xy',
                wheel: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                drag: {
                    enabled: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(225,225,225,0.5)'
                }
            }
        },
        annotation: {
            annotations: {
                box1: {
                    type: 'box',
                    yMin: 0.70,
                    yMax: 0.90,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(204, 204, 255, 0.25)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(204, 204, 255, 0.25)'
                },
                box2: {
                    type: 'box',
                    yMin: 0.30,
                    yMax: 0.50,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(1, 121, 111, 0.25)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(1, 121, 111, 0.25)'
                },
                line: {
                    type: 'line',
                    scaleID: 'x',
                    value: Date.now(),
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    borderWidth: 3,
                }
            }
        }
    },
    scales: {
        x: {
            type: 'realtime',
            realtime: {
                refresh : 5000, // 5 seconds
                ttl: 172800000, //2 days
                duration: 7200000, //2 hours
                delay: -3600000, // - 1 hour
                frameRate: 0.20,
                onRefresh: chart => {
                    const line = chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations.line;
                    chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
                        if(dataset != chart.data.datasets[1]){
                            dataset.data.push({
                                x: Date.now(),
                                y: Math.random()
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    line.value = Date.now();
                }
            }
        },
        y:{}
    }
}
```

In the image below the upper chart is not zoomed and the lower chart is the result after dragging an area.
The selected area should be the only thing visible, the axes should be resized showing only the interval selected and the scrolling effect should stop.
While in this case the selected area moves when the chart updates but the other data is hidden and no resizing is made on the x axes.

[image]

Comment: I don't see obvious problems in your code, so it may be a limitation or incompatibility of chartjs-plugin-streaming. If you use a built-in X axis, does it work as expected?

Comment: For future reference, pasting the code itself, in English, is typically more helpful than a screenshot of an IDE or text editor. It's easier to read, and it lets other Stack Overflow users copy and paste the code if they want to try it themselves.

Comment: @JoshKelley thank you for the suggestion I will paste the code. 
With a built-in X axis and a line chart it works but after dragging the selected area is not well centered. So it works but not exactly as I would like.